# Modeling simple linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling

This should be pretty simple but I'm blanking on this. I need to model (graph) how path 1 becomes equally as efficient as path 2 as the distance of path 2 increases.

distance of path 1 (from A to B) = $10$

distance of path 2 (from A to C) = $y$

The path is a path taken by a forklift driver. The vehicle speed is $2.2\, m/s$. The paths are measured in meters.

On path $1$, there is an added flat time of $30$ seconds (due to something he has to stop and do). On path $2$, there is an added flat time of $10$ seconds.

So in summary:

$$\frac{x}{2.2} + 30 = t_\text{path $1$} \ \ \ \ \ where \ \ \  x>0$$
$$\frac{y}{2.2} + 10 = t_\text{path $2$} \ \ \ \ \ where \ \ \ y>0$$

I know that once the distance of path $2 = 54$ meters, both routes take the same amount of time ($34.545$ seconds). But I can't figure out how to put this into equations that I can use to graph.

I can clarify anything if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Color scheme: $\color{blue}{time}$, $\color{red}{distance}$, $\color{purple}{velocity}$

---

Given a velocity $v$, the time to go from A to B is
$$
 \color{blue}{t_{1}}(\color{purple}{v}) = 
\frac{\color{red}{10}}{\color{purple}{v}} + 
\color{blue}{30}.
$$
The time to go from A to C is
$$
 \color{blue}{t_{2}}(\color{purple}{v}) = 
\frac{\color{red}{y}}{\color{purple}{v}} + 
\color{blue}{10}
$$

When $\color{red}{y}$ is small $\color{blue}{t_{2}}<\color{blue}{t_{1}}$; when $\color{red}{y}$ is larger, $\color{blue}{t_{2}}>\color{blue}{t_{1}}$.

---

Find the value of $\color{red}{y}$ for which
$$
\color{blue}{t_{1}}(\color{purple}{v}) =
\color{blue}{t_{2}}(\color{purple}{v})
\tag{1}
$$

Solving $(1)$, 
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \color{blue}{t_{1}}(\color{purple}{v}) &=
  \color{blue}{t_{2}}(\color{purple}{v}) \\
%
\frac{\color{red}{10}}{\color{purple}{v}} + 
\color{blue}{30} &=
\frac{\color{red}{y}}{\color{purple}{v}} + 
\color{blue}{10}
%
\end{align}
$$
The distance is
$$
\color{red}{y} = \color{red}{10} +  \color{blue}{20}\color{purple}{v} 
$$

---

Given $\color{purple}{v}=2.2$, the distance is $\color{red}{y}=\color{red}{54}$.

[image: solution]